# JSON parsing and AsyncTask error

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to do a register and login function but there is a problem with JSON and also AsyncTask. Here is the logcat error.

```
02-06 04:18:08.857: E/JSON(1160): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>n<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>n<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>n</BODY></HTML>n
02-06 04:18:08.857: E/JSON Parser(1160): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-06 04:18:08.887: W/dalvikvm(1160): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured  while executing doInBackground()
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterTask.java:76)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at my.fyp.inticlassifieds.RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterTask.java:1)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 04:18:08.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     ... 4 more
```

This is the class with the AsyncTask used:

```
public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private RegisterActivity activity;
private int id = -1;
private JSONParser jsonParser;
private static String loginURL = "http://10.2.2.0/project/index.php";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.2.2.0/project/index.php";
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private int responseCode = 0;

public RegisterTask(RegisterActivity activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    EditText userName = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    EditText passwordEdit = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    EditText userContact = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerContact);
    String contact = userContact.getText().toString();
    String email = userName.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();
    Log.v(email, password);
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(email, password, contact);

    // check for login response
    try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            // registerErrorMsg.setText("");
            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                // user successfully registred
                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                        activity.getApplicationContext());
                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                // Clear all previous data in database
                userFunction.logoutUser(activity.getApplicationContext());
                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                        json.getString(KEY_UID),
                        json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                // successful registration
                responseCode = 1;
            } else {
                // Error in registration
                responseCode = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer responseCode) {
    EditText userName = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    EditText passwordEdit = (EditText) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    String s = userName.getText().toString();

    if (responseCode == 1) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        activity.registerReport(responseCode);
        userName.setText("");
        passwordEdit.setText("");
    }
    if (responseCode == 0) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        activity.registerReport(responseCode);
    }
}
}
```

or could the error possibly be from the php itself?

```
<?php
/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * 
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
     $tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["contact"] = $user["contact_no"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["year_joined"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($email, $contact_no, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["contact"] = $user["contact_no"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["year_joined"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

Change the link and now I have this error.

```
02-06 09:45:18.168: E/JSON(1697): <br />n<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: require_once(include/DB_Functions.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Softwares\wamp\www\project\index.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>n<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>n<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>692600</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\Softwares\wamp\www\project\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>n</table></font>n<br />n<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Softwares\wamp\www\project\index.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>n<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>n<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>692600</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\Softwares\wamp\www\project\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>n</table></font>n
```

Comment: You have NPE in RegisterTask.java:76 .. which line is that?

Comment: @M.Sameer if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing to a wrong url: 404 - Not found,

This is what you're trying to parse:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>n<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>n<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>n</BODY></HTML>
```

As you can see is not a JSON, but an HTML page. Test your url pointing to it directly from a browser. You should see a JSON formatted string.

Comment: what url should i put?

Comment: @firaga the url of your php page I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using wrong url. You are getting 404 error page as reponse, and you are trying to parse html as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Value !DOCTYPE" review your url, and servlet or firewall cfg